# How can I make Google OAuth2 authentication work?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-socialauth

I'm using the excellent [Django Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) app to handle logins from a variety of services. This works nicely with Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn but I can't figure out why it will not work with Google. I have got this message numerous times trying all the options that I can think:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://dev.mysite.com/complete/google-oauth2/
next=/close_login_popup/
state=OHZtGyZPyrM0XUjzEsf8dv22VAZGXSY6
display=page
client_id=820357455247-4levikqugduodacfc8j3b5dhsvmbbnnb.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

To create the API key, I went to https://code.google.com/apis/ then filled out the form using the following steps:

[image]

Then, I chose 'Installed Application' which I don't fully understand but most documentation suggest this option. I have tried both other options without success:

[image]

If I try creating a `Web Application` specifying `http://.dev.mysite.com` I get the following error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://dev.mysite.com/complete/google-oauth2/ did not match a registered redirect URI

Learn more

Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
access_type=online
redirect_uri=http://dev.mysite.com/complete/google-oauth2/
next=/close_login_popup/
state=xcpu93i7XJJmYlwXnRbkfgEwsbbR1O7c
display=page
client_id=606300275392.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

My objective is to have a link that someone can click on, give permissions to Google and then log in to my site. I'm testing this on the actual site, `wwww.dev.mysite.com` and when trying the other options for key generation I specified `dev.mysite.com`. I would appreciate any suggestions of what to try next as I've run out of ideas.

Comment: You should specify it as `Web Application` and set `http://dev.mysite.com/complete/google-oauth2/` as the redirect URI.

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work? For some reason, extra scopes isn't working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735648/how-can-i-get-google-auth2-authentication-with-extra-scopes-to-work