# How can I get Google Auth2 authentication with Extra Scopes to work?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-socialauth

I've set up my Django social auth according to the documentation. With the following:

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH_EXTRA_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID      = *client id here*
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET  = *client secret here*
```

In the API console, I have set it to a web application with the Redirect URI as omab says:

```
http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/
```

In my template I have:

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'google' %}" class="google_login_button">Login with Google </a>
```

However, when I test the application the oAuth doesn't ask for "calendar permissions", just the default email ones.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, it was a silly mistake. The link should be:

{% url socialauth_begin 'google-oauth2' %}

I misinterpreted the documentation when it said write in the name of whatever is in the backend.

Hope this helps future people.

Comment: note: in the newest Django, there will be quotes around the socialauth_begin

Answer (score 1):

To save someone using the new python-social-auth and django > 1.4

Use this :

```
{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}
```